How to display how much time is left till next alarm goes off using Shortcuts?
One of the things I miss coming from Android to iOS is that in Android's Clock app, it displays how much time is left till the next alarm goes off, and when I enable an alarm, a little notification pops up telling me how much time till that alarm goes off.
I don't want to use Sleep Focus as a workaround because I don't only use alarms for sleep, and I have multiple alarms throughout the day.
I don't want to audibly ask Siri nor get an audible response. I just want to quietly look at my phone.
I don't want to use a 3rd party alarm app because they have a lot of requirements in order to ring properly. When I have Do Not Disturb or Silent Mode enabled or don't have the app open, I don't want to have to worry about whether my alarm will go off or not.
In order to get the native Clock app to do what I want, I would have to create a shortcut, but I'm really struggling to create one that works. I started with:

Find All Alarms
Get Total Time between Current Date and Alarms
Show notification Your alarm will ring in Time Between Dates

That'll show me time since the previous alarm, not time till the next alarm (I guess because dates aren't taken into consideration, just the hours of the day). If I switch the order of Total Time between, the shortcut no longer prompts me for which alarm I want to check. If I add logic like "if Current Date after alarm, then add 1 day to alarm", Time Between Dates is empty. When I try to find more details about the Alarms data type, I surprisingly find no documentation.
Can you help me create a shortcut that works? Bonus if it can automatically trigger when I enable an alarm.
Note that I use 24-hour time.

"Siri, how long until my next alarm?"

I use timers instead of alarms as they are shown natively with time counting to the next one on the Lock Screen. Let me edit this if I can get a control center widget to do the same.

A limitation with timers is that I can't set recurring timers and can't set timers for more than 24 hours from now.

Sounds good - if someone figures out automation, they might answer as well.
